# How to stop the display of two terminal 'summaries' in VS Code on Macos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am using VS Code to program in Python, but was running into an issue, VS Code was using the current open folder as the active directory instead of the directory the file was in. Therefore, I went into my settings.json and changed `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir":` from `false` to `true`. However, what this ended up doing is navigating to the open folder, and then navigating to the file's directory every time I ran the file in the terminal. You can see this in the screen shot below.

[Screenshot of my code editor page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEL2e.png)

As you can see, every time I run the file, it prints the first snippet/ summary:

`ishaanbhagat at Ishaans-Macbook in test`

`$ cd "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Personal/Programming/Ishaan's Python/test"`

and then in the following line the second snippet/ summary:

`ishaanbhagat at Ishaans-Macbook in test`

`$ /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Personal/Programming/Ishaan's Python/test/test.py"`

`hello`

I would only like it to display the second snippet of text or summary, which as you can see is the only one which actually prints the output of `hello`. The first snippet is redundant, and distracts me by taking up a lot of space on my terminal. Could anyone help me with this?

TL, DR: As you can see in the screenshot, my VS Code terminal is displaying a summary twice, with the second one being the only 'useful' one. I would like the terminal to only display the second summary. Thank you very much

Comment: The first is not redundant, and is necessary or else the `python3` command wouldn't be able to find the correct file to run. Not familiar with VS but you could open the preferences and look for something about changing the directory at run time.

Comment: I understand that it may be necessary for the software, I would just like it to not show me that first block of code as it is distracting and takes up a large portion of the terminal. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. We've offered alternatives for you to employ, if you don't like them or find that it doesn't fit your personal coding style, that's fine but reposting the same question expecting different results isn't the case here, there really is no other way to accomplish what you want other than what's been shown to you

Answer (score 0):

When I set '`python.terminal.executeInFileDir`' to false, the terminal only displays the second part of what you said.

If you just want the console information to be concise, you could refer to the following methods:

1. Set '`"console": "integratedTerminal"`' in the launch.json file, the running result will appear in a separate cmd window, and only the result will be displayed.
2. Try to download an extended application that can provide related functions in the VSCode extension store, for example: Code Runner;

More references:[Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) and [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).